# Send parameters via url (urllib) to another machine

Tags: python, django, urllib

I am developing a python script that opens a file, gets the data inside this file and send it via url to a Django server.

```
import os
import urllib

stockPath = "/Desktop/myfile.txt"

f = open(stockPath)
mydata = f.readline()

print (mydata)

params = urllib.urlencode({'mydata': mydata})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/%s" % params)

print (f.geturl())
```

This is working perfect in local. Now for some reason I have to start the Django server in another machine.
Of course I install python and django in that new machine and I start Django server. So everything is running ok. 
This new machine is in the same network as mine, so I can reach it, the ping works.

The problem is that if I change the ip address for the new one, it doesn't work:

```
f = urllib.urlopen("http://10.32.2.94:8000/home/%s" % params)
```

I would be gratefull if sombebody could help me.

Comment: Can you please explain more how it doesn't work? Do you see incoming request in logs?

Comment: Yes I see this error: IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 111] Connection refused

Comment: Did you try what @jonatron suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen on all interfaces, for example:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

By default it only listens locally.